# PLSQL NULL or Empty collection in table SELECT

Tags: plsql, collections

I am trying to figure out a clean way of qualifying on a table type that may be null or empty. Below is what I have tried so far but that results in a

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

```
DECLARE
    V_TEMP_IDS V500.T_TEMP_IDS := V500.T_TEMP_IDS(123, 124);

    TYPE T_RESULTS IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
    V_RESULTS T_RESULTS;
BEGIN

    SELECT TEMP_ID BULK COLLECT INTO V_RESULTS FROM PEOPLE
    WHERE ACTIVE = 1
        AND TEMP_ID IN (COALESCE(NULLIF((SELECT * FROM TABLE(V_TEMP_IDS)), 0), TEMP_ID));

    dbms_output.put_line(SQL%ROWCOUNT);

END;
```

I would like to select all rows if the collection is null or empty but if it has entries, such as in this example, to include them in the qualification. Hope that makes sense!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NULLIF((SELECT * FROM TABLE(V_TEMP_IDS)), 0) -- is not allowed.
```

If `SELECT * FROM TABLE(V_TEMP_IDS)` returns multiple rows, `nullif` won't work.

```
(SELECT NULLIF(*, 0) FROM TABLE(V_TEMP_IDS)) -- should be what you want to do..
```

Comment: Thanks, the * is not valid, how would I reference the value from the type?

Comment: Used the column_value keyword. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Assuming the second version is meant to be applied as a subquery, with the `*` replaced by the `column_value` [pseudocolumn](https://docs.oracle.com/apps/search/search.jsp?word=pseudocolumn&product=e50529-01&book=SQLRF), that gives 0 rows when `v_temp_ids` is null or empty, and the `nullif` expression doesn't achieve anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether `v_temp_ids` is null or empty, use the `is null` and `is empty` operators:

```
declare
    v_temp_ids t_temp_ids := t_temp_ids(123, 124);

    type t_results is table of number;
    v_results t_results;
begin
    select temp_id bulk collect into v_results from people
    where  active = 1
    and    (   temp_id member of v_temp_ids
            or v_temp_ids is empty
            or v_temp_ids is null );

    dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount);
end;
```

Test a null collection with

```
v_temp_ids t_temp_ids;
```

Test an empty collection with

```
v_temp_ids t_temp_ids := t_temp_ids();
```